Calling function only once with return type
A function is getting called from two completely different places and I want to run that function only once in a threaded safe environment. Consider this scenario:
use std::sync::{Once, Mutex};
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref INIT: Once = Once::new();
    static ref VALUE: Mutex<Option<bool>> = Mutex::new(None);
}

fn expensive_function() -> bool {
    println!("Expensive computation happening...");
    false
}

fn get_value() -> bool {
    INIT.call_once(|| {
        *VALUE.lock().unwrap() = Some(expensive_function());
    });
    VALUE.lock().unwrap().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    // First call - will run expensive_function
    println!("First call: {}", get_value());
    
    // Second call - will return cached value
    println!("Second call: {}", get_value());
}

This works and gives the ouput as expected and is using the mutexes to take care of threaded environment.
Expensive computation happening... First call: false Second call: false
However, there are certain cases which I am not able to think and need help from the experts. 1. What if the thread is poisned and 2. So many unwraps() are not good I believe.
What are the suggestions from the community here? The second call could be in other files as well.
I have tried making taking care of poisened thread explicitly and I could not make it work. Also tried with match statements to avoid unwraps and got confused.

Is there some reason you're avoiding OnceLock or LazyLock here?

not really. @cdhowie

As mentioned in the comments, using std::sync::LazyLock allows you to get rid of both Option and Mutex, eliminating both unwraps:
fn get_value() -> bool {
    static VALUE: LazyLock<bool> = LazyLock::new(|| expensive_function());
    *VALUE
}

Playground
If you need to pass arguments to expensive_function(), use OnceLock instead:
fn get_value() -> bool {
    static VALUE: OnceLock<bool> = OnceLock::new();
    // here you can pass arbitrary data to expensive_function()
    *VALUE.get_or_init(|| expensive_function())
}

Playground
If you actually do need to occasionally modify the data, then you'll still need the Mutex and its unwrap due to poisoning. This unwrap is something you learn to accept as a pattern - after all, if the mutex is really poisoned (the thread that held it panicked), then you probably want to propagate the panic to the threads that attempt to use it. And if you still find the mutex-related unwrap() unpalatable, you can switch from std::sync::Mutex to parking_lot::Mutex, which doesn't have the poisoning feature.

Thanks. Follow up question: Will the expensive_function be called at the start of the program or at the invocation of get_value()?

@HemantBhargava It will be called at the first invocation of get_value(). (This is easy to verify by just adding a print statement at the beginning of main().)

I see. Thanks man. And how do you suggest to pass the parameters to expensive_function?

@HemantBhargava If you need to pass parameters then you should just use OnceLock. The difference between OnceLock and LazyLock is where the populating function is supplied.

Also it seems that the code is subject to race-condition. Suppose you call get_value twice very quickly. One of the two calls will enter the INIT, the other will continue. If you are unlucky the second thread will acquire the mutex before the first one. The first unwrap works well (on poisonning). The second unwrap (on the option) will fail because we did not perform any computation yet. Worst the first thread is now stuck in the INIT waiting for the second thread to release the Mutex.
However this is an edge-case and you would need to be very unlucky to hit it.
For the second point, I don't believe that having unwrap is bad on mutex result (.lock().unwrap()). If a thread is poisonned that means that part of the program has crashed, it would then make sense that the whole program should crash (recovering from crash add a lot of complexity).

There is no race condition in the OP's code. This statement from the answer is incorrect: One of the two calls will enter the INIT, the other will continue. As explained in Once::call_once() docs, the other call won't continue, it will block until the initialization is done. Therefore all unwraps will succeed, regardless of timing.
